# PHP Function - Cannot unset $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, mysql, session

I cannot unset a session variable for a PHP Function,

From the code below, If I enter a review into a site, with the
`$_SESSION['KEYWORD']` data  it will post the correct data, but if I want to 
leave another review through a different `$_SESSION` variable, once it is added into MySQL it displays the value of the first review I entered `$_SESSION['KEYWORD']` in this example...

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
<?php include('db_connect.inc');?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />  



<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['SUBURB'])) {
    $VAR = $_SESSION['SUBURB'];
    Set_Review($VAR);
    unset($VAR);

} elseif (isset($_SESSION['KEYWORD'])) {
        $VAR = $_SESSION['KEYWORD'];
        Set_Review($VAR);
        unset($VAR);

} elseif (isset($_SESSION['LOCATION'])) {
        $VAR = $_SESSION['LOCATION'];
        Set_Review($VAR);
        unset($VAR);

} elseif (isset($_SESSION['RATING'])) {
        $VAR = $_SESSION['RATING'];
        Set_Review($VAR);
        unset($VAR);

}
?>


<?php
function Set_Review($VAR) {
    include('db_connect.inc');
    $result = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO dog_parks.reviews (review_text, username, date, rating, item) VALUES (:review, :id, :date, :rating, :park_value)");
    $result->bindParam(':review', $value1);
    $result->bindParam(':id', $value2);
    $result->bindParam(':date', $value3);
    $result->bindParam(':rating', $value4);
    $result->bindParam(':park_value', $value5);

    $value1 = $_POST['review'];
    $value2 = $_SESSION['id'];
    $value3 = $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $value4 = $_POST['rating'];
    $value5 = trim($VAR,    "'\"");
    $result->execute();
    echo "<h3>Review entry Successful, you will now be redirected to the home page</h3>";
    header( "refresh:5; url=index.php" );
    unset($VAR);
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you unsetting the session variable or the assigned variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unsetting the `$VAR` variable, not your `$_SESSION` variable. Try:

```
unset($_SESSION['KEYWORD'];
```

Comment: I don't think that will work as it is executing a function

Comment: I think the same, he needs to unset the $_SESSION['var'], not $VAR

Comment: If you think this answer is correct, please upvote it to show to others that this answer might be the actual answer :)

Comment: @Dacaspex Needed to be more specific on where to put your code..., i have solved issue see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Pass by reference: `function Set_Review(&$VAR)`. Use "&" before $VAR.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

You will pass the memory address of $_SESSION variable, and then you can unset($VAR) the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think `unset()`ing the `$_SESSION` array is a bad way to do it.
Just call `session_destroy()`

http://php.net/manual/it/function.session-destroy.php

If you want to delete only a part of the session data, try to enclose all those data in an array:

```
$_SESSION["deleteme"] = array();

$_SESSION["deleteme"]["val1"] = "someval";
```

Then:

```
unset($_SESSION["deleteme"]);
```

Comment: session_destroy() I cannot use this as I have a login session as well which will kill it    
(Can only leave 'review' if your logged in)

Comment: If you unset the entire $_SESSION variable you will get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue..

Under each statement I added unset($_SESSION['session name here']);

```
    <?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['SUBURB'])) {
    $VAR = $_SESSION['SUBURB'];
    Set_Review($VAR);
    unset($_SESSION['SUBURB']);

} elseif (isset($_SESSION['KEYWORD'])) {
        $VAR = $_SESSION['KEYWORD'];
        Set_Review($VAR);
        unset($_SESSION['KEYWORD']);

} elseif (isset($_SESSION['LOCATION'])) {
        $VAR = $_SESSION['LOCATION'];
        Set_Review($VAR);
        unset($_SESSION['LOCATION']);

} elseif (isset($_SESSION['RATING'])) {
        $VAR = $_SESSION['RATING'];
        Set_Review($VAR);
        unset($_SESSION['RATING']);

}
?>
```